# Swiper Scroll to Top slide with customscrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slider, vertical-scrolling

I lost a few days trying to make top position in view on other slide than active slide. I use plugin: idangero.us/swiper/. However, didn't work when I join above plugin with [malihu.plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) and I dont know what I'm doing wrong.. **PLEASE help me, anbody**...

If I use only idangero.plugin then everythink work: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tch8rLxk/) but after join next plugin scrollbar no working scroll to top on (other than active) slides.

**How I can join both plugin?**

In malihu plugi part of code responsible for srolling:

```
_wrapperScroll=function(){
        var $this=$(this),d=$this.data(pluginPfx),
            namespace=pluginPfx+"_"+d.idx,
            wrapper=$("#mCSB_"+d.idx+"_container").parent();
        wrapper.bind("scroll."+namespace,function(e){
            if(wrapper.scrollTop()!==0 || wrapper.scrollLeft()!==0){
                $(".mCSB_"+d.idx+"_scrollbar").css("visibility","hidden"); /* hide scrollbar(s) */
            }
        });
    },
```

In dev show code in browser (ff) I can see:

```
mCSB_scrollTools mCSB_3_scrollbar (...) mCSB_scrollTools_vertical
```

Where:

```
mCSB_X_scrollbar
```

is propably equal X malihu scrollbar in X slide.
X is number of slide and scrollbar

So what should I edit/do to make it work and where paste it in idangero plugin

I realy need to your help with that...

best regards

Comment: Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohhd4hxm/) where I use both plugin and  it isn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using custom scrollbar on the slides, you need to use the script's API to control it. The mCustomScrollbar plugin defines a  [`scrollTo` method](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#methods-section-scrollTo), which is available on the element you attached the scrollbar to.

If you want to reset scrollbar position on all slides in the slider except current slide, inside the `onSlideChangeEnd` callback call

```
$(hook.slides).not(':eq(' + hook.activeIndex + ')').mCustomScrollbar('scrollTo', 0);
```

Comment: Great answer, It's work but the error was elsewhere. In Past I didn't know why it still no working so I decided to rewrite in this time (no paste) and that's run without errors :) think that was a hidden character during copy-paste by me. It explains everything. Thank you very much for help.